# why my page number in SSRS dashboard doesnt displays in the right corner of each page?

Tags: sql, vb.net, reporting-services

My dashboard consist of 10 sub-reports. And some of those sub-reports are several pages.In a page footer of a dashboard I entered expression in a textbox:

```
="Page " & Globals!OverallPageNumber & " of " & Globals!OverallTotalPages
```

which gives me the page number, but how can I move this to the right corner?
As you can see on a below picture the expression already further right than even sub-report itself. What else can I do? 
This is my report properties for the Dashboard:
[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the table you have is a Matrix with Column grouping. The grouping is expanding and pushing the width but unfortunately, that doesn't push the **footer** out.

Since you can't make the position dynamic, you'll have to figure out where the sub report page ends and extend the main report's width to fit the page number.

It looks like the first column is 4 inches wide and the matrix columns are 2 inches wide. I would put the text box at 15 inches and make it 1 inch wide.

Comment: But if I expand the dasboard even a little bit its gonna give me extra blank pages.

Comment: My tables in subreports are 15 in wide. My matrix with a column groups are 5 in wide. Is there anything I should do with that?

Comment: Oh, I think I got it. Thanks for the idea. You full of those great advice's, whats your experience in SQL?,